# How can we connect to a git account from Google cloud shell which already has git installed?

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am able to see git already installed in cloud shell. Also, when i fire
'git config --list' command i get below output.

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper=gcloud.sh
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
```

Which credentials are these? And how can I connect to my github account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. I'll mention what worked for me.

I set up git configuration using

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

when I cloned my private repo using,

```
git clone https://[your-git-repo].git
```

I had to enter my GitHub password. Then I performed whatever changes I had to make and after commiting did

```
git push
```

Again I had to provide my github password and the changes were pushed to my private repo.
Please let me know if there is any better/ideal way to achieve the same.

edit:
Password Authentication has been removed from Aug2021 onwards. So now, this solution won't work.
One of the alternatives to authenticate to GIT account is by generating Personal Access Token. Details can be found here

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic

Once token is generated, save the token and it can be used instead of password to authenticate to Github.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-private-github-repos) you can add your github account to the GCP Cloud Shell to upload your file to private git repository.

Comment: But that's for Cloud Build not Cloud Shell.   And it's quite involved, so even if it also works for Cloud Shell, the other solutions seem better.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add your ssh key to your deploy:

1. Login to GitHub.
2. In the upper-right corner, click your profile photo, then click **Your profile**.
3. On your profile page, click **Repositories**, then click the name of your repository.
4. From your repository, click **Settings**.
5. In the sidebar, click **Deploy Keys**, then click **Add deploy key**.
6. Provide a title, paste your public SSH key from `workingdir/id_github.pub`.
7. Select **Allow write access** if you want this key to have write access to the repository. A deploy key with write access lets a deployment push to the repository.
8. Click **Add key**. Delete the SSH key from your disk:

```
rm id_github*
```

Once you do that, I found some documentation to generate credentials that maybe you can use.

To connect a github account to google look this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mirroring-gitlab-repositories-to-cloud-source-repositories#generate_static_credentials) and then you continue with the part of the git configuration.

For the part that you ask for the credentials find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#add_the_repository_as_a_remote) this is the Google credentials.